# Left indentation of hanging line text same as left indentation of the first line in PowerPoint using VBA

Tags: vba, powerpoint

I am trying to make the hanging lines on a presentation slide consistent so that both the hanging lines and first line have the same left indentation.

For example, in the screenshot attached below, I want the words "Thousands", "surface", and "activities" to start at the same left margin (as shown in the blue highlighted part in the slide). Any information on thus is so helpful.

[image: An image that Describes my problem]

Answer (score 0):

From your screen shot, I doubt that paragraph indentation/first line indentation is the cause. However, if it is, this is the VBA that should fix it. The TextFrame2 object is the one with updated paragraph spacing for current versions of PowerPoint:

```
  With ActiveWindow.Selection.ShapeRange.TextFrame2.TextRange.Paragraphs(Start:=1, Length:=1).ParagraphFormat
    .FirstLineIndent = -18
    .LeftIndent = 18
  End With
```